# CoreData [Int64] transformable, transform to usable array outside of Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a CoreData entity with various values. Sometimes I want to export the values to Json to share with another app. My Transformed [Int64] turns into data.
How can I transform it back? For instance in javascript?

Comment: Why don't you transform it back into [Int64] in the reverse of your transform?

Comment: Because I use the CoreData entity to do that, and all it tells me is that it uses "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData".

Comment: How do you "export" to JSON exactly?

Comment: Good point. I just grab the sqlite file and let a third party app convert to JSON. But the end result is the same.

Comment: I deleted the javascript tag because I thought this was a swift question since usually dealing with core data and the underlying storage is done from within the app. But now I am not so sure if this was right to do so, could you be a bit more specific in what you are asking?

Comment: "let a third party app convert to JSON" So the issue is on the third party app, no? How does it exports the value? As Raw Data ("hex")? Then, in JS, you need to decode them, right? That's the issue? Because it wasn't clear, and as said by @JoakimDanielson then, it's more a JS issue (and how is encoded the Array, indeed), but which transformer did you used?

Comment: It's not necessarily a third party app issue. Swift encodes the [Int64] through NSKeyedArchiver. If you read this value directly from CoreData, it's encoded. So how do we get the encoded value back to a normal array of integers? 
Example encoded value:  YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGBwpYJHZlcnNpb25ZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3BYJG9iamVjdHMSAAGGoF8QD05TS2V5ZWRBcmNoaXZlctEICVRyb290gAGkCwwSE1UkbnVsbNINDg8RWk5TLm9iamVjdHNWJGNsYXNzoRCAAoADEAbSFBUWF1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQXJyYXmiFhhYTlNPYmplY3QIERokKTI3SUxRU1heY251d3l7fYKNlp6hAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAGQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKo

Comment: No. Becase that's base 64. If you decode it, you'll see that by using `NSUnkeyedArchiver`, it will always add some values like `bplist00
X$versionY$archiverT$topX$objects�_NSKeyedArchiver TrootU$null...` at start. So the decoding isn't easily done in JS...

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to think it's easier to write a new function that just writes a json file directly from the app. Because in the app, the array is handled correctly. Thanks for thinking with me.

Comment: But if you used a `JSONEncoder` & `JSONDecoder` for the transformer with both, it might work, as the encoding might be only raw JSON hex. But that'd need a migration though on your model. I'm not sure about the behavior, you need to check it beforehand on a sample project (before doing the heavy migration).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by writing an export to json directly from the app. Then the array is intact.

```
let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first!
    let fileurl =  dir.appendingPathComponent("export.json")
                
                var array: [String] = ["[\n"]
                for value in values
                  if let value = (value.toJSON()) {
                  array.append(value + ",\n")
                  }
                }
                array.append("]")

                let data = array.joined().data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
                

                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileurl.path) {
                    if let fileHandle = try? FileHandle(forUpdating: fileurl) {
                        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
                        fileHandle.write(data)
                        fileHandle.closeFile()
                    }
                } else {
                    try! data.write(to: fileurl, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
                }
```

Using .toJSON() which I got here [CoreData object to JSON in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237755/coredata-object-to-json-in-swift-3) from @Mike_NotGuilty.

```
extension NSManagedObject {
  func toJSON() -> String? {
    let keys = Array(self.entity.attributesByName.keys)
    let dict = self.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: keys)
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let reqJSONStr = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
        return reqJSONStr
    }
    catch{}
    return nil
  }
}
```

Edit: Forgot, above function has an error because the last value also gets a , at the end, leading to a corrupt JSON. I use something like this:

```
for i in values.indices {
     if i != values.count - 1 {
        if let value = (values[i].toJSON()) {
            array.append(value + ",\n")
            }
      } else {
        if let value = (values[i].toJSON()) {
            array.append(value + "\n")
            }
      }
}
```